# Does DHCP on dd-wrt support the absence of the default route?

Tags: dhcp, router, dnsmasq, gateway, dd-wrt

I have one reason to flash dd-wrt onto my router (rt-ac66u), which is to be able to not assign any default route via DHCP. The stock firmware  doesn't seem to be able to do this.

Dd-wrt appears to be using dnsmasq as its DHCP server, which in itself supports this with `dhcp-option=3`.

Since I understand an install is not without some risk, and that I apparently can't expect this functionality even from router manufacturers, I wanted to confirm beforehand whether dd-wrt definitely supports this? Or will it insist on itself as a default route (like every other router I own) if I leave the option blank?

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off asking this on one of the DD-WRT forums

Comment: @roaima No doubt! But there are forums for just about every niche and I'd prefer to not sign up everywhere (especially when I'm not yet invested), in favor of concentrating answers here on SE. The format, longevity and discoverability is better here as well.

Comment: Or just install dd-wrt in a virtual machine and test it out and see if behaves the way you want.